# How to export files with gradient on inkscape

Tags: inkscape, export, gradient

So, I was doing this thing to get used to Inkscape and I did certain things using some gradient: [image]

Now the problem is:
When I try to export it and open with Windows standard image viewer , I get this: [image]

On the other hand, the first image is the one exported and opened by Stack with no errors on the gradient level.

Why does this happen?

Comment: The windows image viewer, as far as I know, doesn't support transparency.  So if you are exporting as a PNG with transparency, it won't display properly in that viewer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first image has transparency. The grey gradient around your emerald is actually partially transparent black and its final appearance depends on what background it gets. GDSE puts it on white. Obviously your image viewer gives to it the black background.

If you want to be sure your image is seen properly, you should make a version with white background and export it as JPG without transparency.

So, the export as PNG has been succesful. Maybe in some Windows support forum someone could show, how to configure the windows Image preview. Waiting for that you should get some image viewer that shows all the formats you need properly or at least consistently.